Stripe, manage subscription through Customer Portal, (billingPortal)

I have to subscribe to 2 different products for one user.

Is monthly price.
Is meter price.

I want to avoid a meter price (Starter Meter) for the billing portal. And see only the monthly price (Starter)
Also, I did configuration and set only needed products, but Stripe sends me all user subscriptions.
const configuration = await stripe.configurations.create({..})
const session = await stripe.billingPortal.sessions.create({
      customer: stripeCustomerId,
      return_url: RETURN_URL,
      configuration: configuration.id,
});

